# Angular 7 route path opens sourcemap

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a detail page for extra information for each row in my list page but my detail page does not open with router link. The page does not change, the url does not change but in the network tab the app called a sourcemap .js file. Inside it is my entire html, scss, component, module and service code.

I checked if I added the RouterModule inside my page module and the path value for my page. The URL I can read from the router link also has all its dynamic values set and it matches the path.

Am I missing something in my page configuration to make it work ?

I am using fuse theme template version 7.1.0

This is my code snippet:

```
<div class="page-layout blank p-24" fusePerfectScrollbar>
    <h1>List Row Detail</h1>

    <div class="content pb-24" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
        <form class="mat-white-bg mat-elevation-z4 p-24 w-100p" [formGroup]="detailForm">
            <div fxLayout="column">
                <mat-form-field class="w-350 mr-10 pt-10">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Name" class="w-350" type="text" formControlName="Name" readonly="readonly" />
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationService } from '../../xxxx/services/notification.service';
import { IdentificationGeneratorService } from '../../xxxx/services/identification-geneterator.service';
import { Notification } from '../../xxxx/models/notification.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { FuseSplashScreenService } from '@fuse/services/splash-screen.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'row-list-detail',
    templateUrl: './row-list-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./row-list-detail.component.scss'],
})

export class RowListDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    organizationGuid;
    rowListGuid;
    detailForm;

    constructor(private notificationService: NotificationService,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
        private fuseSplashScreenService: FuseSplashScreenService) {
        this.fuseSplashScreenService.hide();
        this.detailForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            Name: [''],

        });

        this.organizationGuid = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['organizationGuid'];
        this.rowListGuid = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['rowListGuid']; 

    }
}

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { RowListDetailComponent } from './row-list-detail.component';
import { InformationDialogModule } from '../../xxxx/components/information-dialog/information-dialog.module';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '**',
        component: RowListDetailComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        RowListDetailComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        FuseSharedModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        InformationDialogModule
    ],
    exports: [
        RowListDetailComponent
    ]
})

export class RowListDetailModule {
}


<div class="page-layout blank p-24" fusePerfectScrollbar>
    <h1>List</h1>
    
    <ngx-datatable class="material" [rows]="list" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="50" [footerHeight]="50"
        [rowHeight]="50" [limit]="20" [sorts]="[{prop: 'Name', dir: 'desc'}]" [cssClasses]="iconsCss">

        <ngx-datatable-column prop="Name" name="Name">
            <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <a [routerLink]="['/Apps/Organizations', organizationGuid , 'Lists', row.rowListGuid, 'Detail']">{{row.Name}} </a>
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>
</div>

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { FuseSharedModule } from '@fuse/shared.module';
import { MsalGuard } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { CheckRedirectUrlService } from 'app/xxxx/services/checkredirecturl.service';

const routes = [
    {
        path: 'Organizations/:organizationGuid/Lists/:rowListGuid/Detail',
        loadChildren: './row-list-detail/row-list-detail.module#RowListDetailModule',
        canActivate: [MsalGuard, CheckRedirectUrlService]
    },
    {
        path: 'Organizations/:organizationGuid/Lists',
        loadChildren: './list/list.module#ListModule',
        canActivate: [MsalGuard, CheckRedirectUrlService]
    }

];

@NgModule({
    imports     : [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        FuseSharedModule
    ]
})
export class AppsModule
{
}
```

Comment: Do you think your question could be answered without including the relevant code?

Comment: Sorry for not adding code, I edited the question and put my code snippet in.

Comment: I found the issue, in the html a textarea element was used for a Date type value. After changing it to input type datetime, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the textarea element was trying to set a Date value defined in my model.
After changing the value field in the model a string the problem was solved the page was successfully loaded and the field in the form including the textarea were set.